# Swing JProgressBar with multiple JLabels below

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, layout-manager, jprogressbar

I have a problem concerning layouts in Swing. I have got a `BorderLayout` and want to add a `JProgressBar` with multiple `JLabels` below in the `NORTH` section of this layout all aligned horizontal next to each other.

It should look something like this:
[image]

I already tried various layouts like for example `GroupLayout` but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Use a `GridLayout` for the labels...

Comment: or also a single GridBagLayout for both the bar and the labels.

Comment: Why not simply [`JProgressBar.setString("Step 1/6");`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html#setString-java.lang.String-)?  Does a `%` value really make sense for a 6 step process?

Comment: @AndrewThompson You are right, but the drawn 6 steps were just an example. Could also be more. So I was asking in general. But thank you anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using a second `JPanel` with a `GridLayout`...

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
add(new JProgressBar(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
JPanel panel = new GridLayout(1, 6);
panel.add(new JLabel("Step 1"));
panel.add(new JLabel("Step 2"));
panel.add(new JLabel("Step 3"));
panel.add(new JLabel("Step 4"));
panel.add(new JLabel("Step 5"));
panel.add(new JLabel("Step 6"));
add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

As an example.

See [How to Use GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) for more details